# what to add before "@" to make it ignore by the system?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, proxy, passwords

This is my configuration file in ubuntu 16.04:

```
Acquire::http::proxy "http://username:**(@)**[@]172.16.115.66:3128/";
Acquire::https::proxy "https://172.16.115.66:3128/";
Acquire::ftp::proxy "ftp://172.16.115.66:3128/";
Acquire::socks::proxy "socks://172.16.115.66:3128/";
```

My proxy password contains '@' as shown covered by small bracket, the one covered by big bracket is used as separation symbol. What to add before my password '@' to make the system know that this one is not a separation one? Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried to send the `@` urlencoded as `%40` ? This would work in most situations, but I'm not sure about `apt` specifically.

```
Acquire::http::proxy "http://username:**%40**@172.16.115.66:3128/";
```

Comment: Worked for me! Thanks @Bernhard